# QScrollArea widget auto resize when adding child widgets

Tags: qt, layout, qscrollarea

I have the following structure:

```
QScrollArea
  - QWidget (with QHBoxLayout)
    - QLabel
    - QLabel
    - QLabel
    ...
```

QLabels are generated automatically with random text.
How to change the size of the widget automatically to fit labels?
At the moment I can see the widget only by setting a fixed size.

**Solution:**

After creating QLabel I store its width:

```
int widthSum = 0;
for ( ... ){
    ...
    widthSum += label->sizeHint().width();
}
```

And after the cycle I set fixed width to widget:

```
widget->setFixedWidth(widthSum);
```

Thanks @shobi for a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use reSize() method on widget .

```
resize(sizeHint())
```

Comment: hm... This method only works for the first generation of QLabels... if I clear widget's layout and do the same it doesn't work. Maybe there is my mistake somewhere. Thanks for answer. +1.